# Generate Data Intervals with Certain Coverage

Tags: dataset, evaluation

I have a time series and I want to generate 100 intervals uniformly distributed (with potential overlaps) on the entire dataset. How can I ensure that the union of these 100 intervals covers 20% of the entire dataset?

Comment: For me, it's not entirely clear what the uniform distribution refers to: Should the *end points* of the interval be uniformly distributed in [0,1]? And what potential additional constraints may exist here? If there is *one* interval among these 100 that coincidentally spans a range of 0.2 of the full interval, then it will be fine (regardless of what all other intervals look like)?

Comment: @Marco13 Suppose the entire dataset contains data points with ids ranges from 0 to 1000. I want to generate 20 intervals of size 10, e.g. [17, 27) where the center of the intervals are uniformly distributed within [0, 1000].

Comment: When 20 intervals of size 10 should cover 20% of the range between 0 and 1000, then these intervals have to be disjoint. However, I think I can *roughly* imagine what you mean, but can't suggest an elegant (and probabilistically "clean") solution, except for brute-force random sampling and repeated tests whether the desired coverage has been reached...

Comment: Maybe you'd like to edit your question with the new information from the comments. It will make the question clearer (and bring it to the top once more, maybe someone else then has an idea...)